# Groovy object properties in map

Tags: groovy

Instead of having to declare all the properties in a map from an object like:

```
prop1: object.prop1
```

Can't you just drop the object in there like below somehow? Or what would be a proper way to achieve this?

```
results: [
    object, 
    values: [
        test: 'subject'
    ]
]
```

Comment: If object is a map, then `*:object`

Comment: I should have mentioned it is a POGO. But I learned something new today from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: *:object.properties seems to work. Thanks

Comment: `object.properties` will sometimes come with extra baggage (properties that are not created by you), see below for a different solution :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

object.properties will give you a `class` as well

You should be able to do:

Given your POGO object:

```
class User {
    String name
    String email
}

def object = new User(name:'tim', email:'tim@tim.com')
```

Write a method to inspect the class and pull the non-synthetic properties from it:

```
def extractProperties(obj) {
    obj.getClass()
       .declaredFields
       .findAll { !it.synthetic }
       .collectEntries { field ->
           [field.name, obj."$field.name"]
       }
}
```

Then, map spread that into your result map:

```
def result = [
    value: true, 
    *:extractProperties(object)
]
```

To give you:

```
['value':true, 'name':'tim', 'email':'tim@tim.com']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using a few libraries here's an option where you convert the object to json and then parse it back out as a map. I added mine to a baseObject which in your case object would extend.

```
class BaseObject {
  Map asMap() {
    def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic()
    Map map = jsonSlurper.parseText(this.asJson())
    return map
  }
  String asJson(){
    def jsonOutput = new groovy.json.JsonOutput()
    String json = jsonOutput.toJson(this)
    return json
  }
}
```

Also wrote it without the  json library originally. This is like the other answers but handles cases where the object property is a List.

```
class BaseObject {
Map asMap() {
    Map map = objectToMap(this)
    return map
}   
def objectToMap(object){
    Map map = [:]
    for(item in object.class.declaredFields){
        if(!item.synthetic){
            if (object."$item.name".hasProperty('length')){
                map."$item.name" = objectListToMap(object."$item.name")
            }else if (object."$item.name".respondsTo('asMap')){
                map << [ (item.name):object."$item.name"?.asMap() ]
            } else{
                map << [ (item.name):object."$item.name" ]
            }
        }
    }
    return map
}

def objectListToMap(objectList){
    List list = []
    for(item in objectList){
        if (item.hasProperty('length')){
            list <<  objectListToMap(item)
        }else {
            list << objectToMap(item)
        }
    }
    return list
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work well

```
*:object.properties
```