# Unable to get a key value called properties "properties": "Value" Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, properties

I'm making API requests to a service which returns a JSON object within the body.

I can't seem to get the value of a key called "properties" within groovy.

Everytime I call `obj.properties` i get the following back

```
{
  "class": "org.json.JSONObject"
}
```

but if I call just the `obj` I get the expected JSON object

```
{
  "dummy1": ,
  "dummy2": false,
  "dummy3": etsad,
  "dummy4": asdfw,
  "dummy5": qweqwe,
  "dummy6": 123123,
  "properties": {
    "country": UK,
   }
}
```

Likewise if I `obj.dummy2` i get `false` it's only when I `obj.properties` do I get the above mentioned response

Comment: try `obj.get('properties')`

Comment: that worked! amazing, thank you

Comment: Your json is incorrect format. Use online editors to verify your json: https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice groovy have a special handling for Object's `properties`, for example for number:

```
def y = 25
print y.properties
```

It will print `[class:class java.lang.Integer]`

So it's part of basic groovy object

See also an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072243/groovy-object-properties-in-map) about getting *non-synthetic properties* from groovy object

As @daggett comment, you can use

```
  obj.get('properties')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14028283/5395858) here on how to access the properties of objects.

The reason obj.properties isn't working is most likely due to the fact that every object will have properties, and in your case `obj.properties` is getting the properties of the JSON object and not the value associated with the key.

Instead of `obj.properties`, consider `obj['properties']`