# Jenkins pipeline - save to file build job properties

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Please help me how can I save to file build job properties
tried in below way, and I get following text in file: [slave:org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@7fb29d4c]

```
def jobsResult      = [:]

pipeline {
    agent { label 'Apps' }
    
    stages {
        stage('Exec Job') 
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Stage name is : ${STAGE_NAME}"
                    try {
                        jobsResult.job_01 = build job: "job_01", propagate: true, wait: true
                        jobsResult.job_02 = build job: "job_02", propagate: true, wait: true
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        echo "Slave job failed, marking build as UNSTABLE"
                        currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
                    }
                    
                    writeFile file: "jobsResults.txt", text: "${jobsResult}"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Sleep') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Stage name is : ${STAGE_NAME}"
                    try {
                        sleep 10
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        echo "Sleep stage failed, but continuing..."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
writeFile file: "jobsResults.txt", text: "${jobsResult}"
```

The string represent of `jobsResult` is write to file, which is `[slave:org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@7fb29d4c]`

You should use `writeJSON` instead, which will serialize the map object into JSON and write to file

```
writeJSON file: "jobsResults.json", json: jobsResult
```

Since `writeJSON` only works for map object, you may need to convert the object to map so that you can successfully save the data to file.

One potential solution is to define the following method [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072243/groovy-object-properties-in-map)

```
def extractProperties(obj) {
    obj.getClass()
       .declaredFields
       .findAll { !it.synthetic }
       .collectEntries { field ->
           [field.name, obj."$field.name"]
       }
}
```

And then change the following line from

```
jobsResult.job_01 = build job: "job_01", propagate: true, wait: true
```

to

```
def job_01 = build job: "job_01", propagate: true, wait: true
jobsResult.job_01 = extractProperties(job)
```

Comment: firstly write JSON should be in following format: 
writeJSON file: 'jobsResults.txt', json: jobsResult

secondary still jobs properties failed to be write to file

Comment: @RomanZinger I see. I just update the answer, I think you may need to convert the object into map first.